# why error code 1 returned by loading .bash_profile in Mac

Tags: mac, bash, .bash-profile

Whenever I open a bash terminal, the error code 1 is returned:

```
Last login: Tue Jan 15 16:19:53 on ttys000
spam@moss:~ $ echo $?
1
```

I found this is caused by last line of code in my `.bash_profile`:

```
test -f $HOME/.debug && export profile_bash_profile='.bash_profile' || return 0
```

If I remove this line, then the error code 0 is returned. I don't understand how this line could cause any problem, because I can source `.bash_profile` with the error code 0:

```
spam@moss:~ $ source .bash_profile
spam@moss:~ $ echo $?
0
```

Update:

Does anyone one know how Mac load ~/.bash_profile? I doubt Mac sources it when a login shell is launched. It seems the `return` command doesn't run as expected - when I put `return 5` as the last line of `~/.bash_profile` and launch a login shell, it does not return error code 5 (and I am sure `~/.bash_profile` is the last script loaded).

Comment: Mac OS X’s `bash` loads its dot files the same way as on other platforms (keeping in mind the OS X Terminal always starts a login shell in a new tab or window). The only explanation that comes to my mind is that there is indeed another file loaded after `.bash__profile`, one in which the exported `profile_bash_profile` is used and triggers an error (hence exit code 1 – possibly because the var is not set to path, but only to a file name?).

Comment: what are the possible files that could be loaded after .bash_profile? I only have ~/.bashrc and don't have ~/.profile, so I don't think I have any other files loaded after .bash_profile.

Comment: That’s difficult to say without access to your system config. Check `.bash_profile` for anything that sources other files (like, say, `.bashrc`), then anything included by `homebrew` if you use that.

Answer (score 5):

Note that what happens when using `return` outside a function without having `source`d the script (e.g. `return`ing from `.bash_profile`) is undocumented in `man bash`.

The difference is in how the return code of a script or function is recorded internally in `bash`. If you `return` a value, that value is assigned the return code of the *calling* code, e.g. the function call you return from, or the `source` command. As there is no such caller when returning from `.bash_profile` during shell initialization, that value is simply discarded. What you're accessing as `$?` is the **return code of the preceding statement**.

Using Apple's [bash-86.1](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-86.1/) as reference:

If you `source` a script, its contents are parsed and executed, until a `return` statement is encountered. Its return value is recorded separately, and it's the responsibility of the caller (`execute_command_internal` in `bash-3.2/execute_cmd.c`) to assign its value to the variable holding the last exit code: `last_command_exit_value`.

If it's called as a startup script, it is loaded via a call to `maybe_execute_file` in the `run_startup_files` function in `bash/shell.c`. It's not regular command execution: While the contents of the file are executed properly, including the final `return`, nobody cares about the actual value you're returning. It is simply discarded.

So, **what behavior are you seeing here**? Essentially the same as if you'd called `return`without argument: Like `return` simply returned the return code of the command preceding it, which, in your case, is the failed test.

**How to get the desired behavior?** Since you can't `exit` from `.bash_profile` without quitting the shell, you need to make sure the command immediately preceding it produces the desired return code, in this case:

```
test -f $HOME/.debug && export profile_bash_profile='.bash_profile' || { true; return; }
```

Comment: So, what to do if I don't have any `test` commands in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei You can experience the same problem with any number of commands assuming you use the same pattern of `return` usage.

Comment: I understand. So it works if I have `some_command \n true; return;`?

Comment: @IulianOnofrei I would assume so. But please note it has been almost four years since I researched and answered this question.

Comment: Thanks! And, sure, no problem, I'll dig into it.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured the following out by trial and error. Maybe a BASH guru can explain some more.

1. `.bashrc` contents:

   ```
   test -f $HOME/existent_file || return 4
   ```

   After opening a new terminal:

   ```
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```
2. `.bashrc` contents:

   ```
   test -f $HOME/non_existent_file || return 4
   ```

   After opening a new terminal:

   ```
   $ echo $?
   1
   ```
3. `.bashrc` contents:

   ```
   function foo () { 
       return 4 
   }
   foo;
   ```

   After opening a new terminal:

   ```
   $ echo $?
   4
   ```
4. `.bashrc` contents:

   ```
   return 4
   ```

   After opening a new terminal:

   ```
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```
5. With the same `.bashrc` as above:

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   $ echo $?
   4
   ```
6. These commands run directly from a terminal:

   ```
   $ test -f $HOME/existent_file  || return 4
   $ echo $?
   0
   $ test -f $HOME/non_existent_file  || return 4
   bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
   $ echo $?
   1
   ```

So, `return` only works from functions and sourced files. I don't know *how* a user's `~/.bashrc` is read but apparently it is not sourced.

Comment: Good detective work, leading to fascinating results!  This seems to be the illustration that goes with Daniel’s answer.  BTW, it ***shouldn’t*** matter, but what platform were you on?  (Mac?)

Comment: @Scott, thanks :). I'm on Linux, Linux Mint Debian to be precise and bash 4.2.36(1).